# Refresh macOS to get rid of stuck info tag

Tags: macos, desktop

Every now and then I get an info tag stuck on my screen on top of all my applications. The only thing I know that will remove it is restarting my computer. Is there an easier way to refresh OSX that would get rid it?

[image: Stuck info tag in OSX Mavericks]

I'm running the latest OSX Mavericks. I tried creating a new desktop deleting the main desktop. The problem persists unto the new desktop.

The tag does go away temporarily when I slide over to the dashboard and when I show the desktop but comes right back when I return to my applications.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Turns out this is a common problem.

One of the following should get rid of the tooltip:

- Hover over another element with a tooltip in the same app that generated the stuck tooltip, as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135041/46587)
- Close the app which you think generated the tooltip
- Log out of macOS and log back in

Comment: logging out worked but still that's rubbish experience, +1 for the answer

Comment: Same is happening in 2020 :D

Comment: Hover over another element with a tooltip in the same app works for me.

Comment: Same is happening in 2022.

Comment: Same is happening in 2023.

Comment: Same is happening in 2024