# "Evernote Premium" text is hovering on my screen, despite Evernote app being closed

Tags: macos, screen-capture, evernote

I have some text hovering over my screen, in all my spaces, for at least the past 2 weeks. I cannot recall when this started. And, unfortunately, I do not know how to replicate it.

Several attempts to contact Evernote for support have been fruitless.

This is what the text looks like :

[image: screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

This text is there whether I'm in a terminal window, running a VM through VMWare, or watching a movie!

[image: watching-movie]

I have uninstalled and quit Evernote, but I'm beginning to think this is not a problem of Evernote.

This is a 13" Macbook Air from mid-2013 running OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: when is the last time you restarted your computer?

Comment: Really interesting problem, try to check this post, maybe it can help in some way. link:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38012/yellow-tooltip-stuck-on-screen

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then logging back in?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. @Victor - this could help me determine what's responsible.

Comment: @dwightk, also a useful suggestion. I restart my computer about every 3 days! Most recently, after I upgraded Evernote to the latest version. My latest find was that if I start the computer in safe mode, the text isn't there. Now to determine which start-up service is responsible :)

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down your Mac should clear text like this.

If it comes back, you’ll need to look at startup items or a safe startup. The steps are different for Intel and Apple Silicon hardware.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255